# Visual Test With Applitools Of a simple CSS class change

Tags: unit-testing

would like to know if there is a tutorial to learn how to test with this tool this type of change?. I meant... I needed to introduce a CSS class change in a component but I don't know how to test it... i've checked youtube but I cant quite understand how would be the best approach...

Answer (score 2):

Edit: Applitools customer support is very helpful - consider contacting them for a more personal assistance.

Applitools is a cloud service that smartly detects changes to your UI that are noticeable to the human eye.
It does so by comparing screenshots taken during your automatic end-to-end tests to baseline images taken during the last test that you approved.
I mention this because you tagged your question as unit-testing. This is not unit-testing as it requires launching a browser (automatically - using Selenium for example) to run the automated tests.

Per your question - you should make sure that you have a baseline image that contains the component in discussion before your class change (do it by running an automated test that calls Applitools Eyes API to create a checkpoint (eyes.checkWindow) when your test reaches a page that contains this component. Then, approve the new test as a baseline, apply your class change and run the test again.

Applitools will let you know if a visual difference occurred following your change. So, for example, if this is just an under-the-hood change - you will not see a visual difference, but if this actually affects the UI then you'll see a visual difference. If you're happy with this difference you simply approve this run as your new baseline.

To show an example I'll use the Applitools tutorial for Selenium + Java. See the comments - you run this once, make your class change and run it again:

```java
import com.applitools.eyes.Eyes;
import com.applitools.eyes.RectangleSize;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;

public class TestApplitoolsWebsite {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException, InterruptedException {

    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

    Eyes eyes = new Eyes();
    // This is your api key, make sure you use it in all your tests.
    eyes.setApiKey("YOUR_API_KEY");

    try {
      // Start visual testing with browser viewport set to 1024x768.
      // Make sure to use the returned driver from this point on.
      driver = eyes.open(driver, "Applitools", "Test Web Page", new RectangleSize(1024, 768));

      driver.get("http://applitools.com");

      // Visual validation point #1
      eyes.checkWindow("Main Page");

      driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".features>a")).click();

      // Visual validation point #2
      // Let's assume this page contains the class you'll change
      eyes.checkWindow("Features page");

      // End visual testing. Validate visual correctness.
      eyes.close();
    } finally {
      // Abort test in case of an unexpected error.
      eyes.abortIfNotClosed();
      driver.close();
    }
  }
}
```

Of course - if your class change impacts several places in the application / website then it's best to make sure your test covers all these places and that you take screenshots of all these places.